# how to make menus by using loop

Tags: delphi

I want make menus and submenus and subsubmenus in Delphi. The total length is 4000 items and it is going to be very define them and given an action individually. I know that I can use loop to define their captions and their onclick. I have tried with different commands but the program doesn’t find those commands.

For example I want compare the products from different companies, let say food. organic or non-organic. dairy has  Milk, yogurt, cheese, cream and so on which each of them has natural, medium or low fat. And so on for other food products. I have made a list of products inn a file so that I can read each item  from the file and put them in menuitem’s caption, when I create them. But I don’t  how I should create the menuitems and add a text in its caption. I have used xtem.Index[i], but the program doesn’t recognize.

When I am ready with the definition of menu, I must make a loop that when I choose an item in menubar, it must appear in a editbox for further calculation, so I haven’t problem with.

Also my problem is to make two types food organic ad non-organic
Each has more than 1000 submenus and each submenus has at least 1 item and it can be that some subsubmenus has few items. So I want make the menu by using loop.

After that when I choose an item it should appears in editbox, so I must use a proper command in the loop for this.

I hope and wish and appreciate if you can help me out for my request and tell me few commands so I can complete my program

Comment: That much items doesn't sound like a job for menu but rather a tree view. Poor user who accidentally close the menu after a long searching for an item.

Comment: 4000 Menu Items... will they even all fit on a normal screen? Heed TLama advise. Please also update your question into a better format. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your UI design is certainly flawed. Beyond that, it is quite possible to create menus dynamically. If you failed to do so then I guess you made a mistake in your code. Which we cannot see. Please revisit the question and add a short example of the code you used to make the menus dynamically. Oh, when you edit the question, please add some structure. Some paragraphs would help.

Comment: You should not really show more than 7 or so menu items and a time, it's too confusing for the users.

Answer (score 3):

You are not very specific about what you want, so I've made you a small example of how to create a MainMenu at runtime. But I agree with the comments it is a BAD  solution.

But any way here it goes:

```
uses
  Menus;


procedure TForm17.CreateMainMenu;
var
  MainMenu: TMainMenu;
  TopMenuItem, MenuItem, SubMenuItem: TMenuItem;
  i, j, k: Integer;
begin
  MainMenu := TMainMenu.Create(Self);

  for i := 0 to 5 do
  begin
    TopMenuItem := TMenuItem.Create(MainMenu);
    TopMenuItem.Caption := 'Top menu item #' + i.ToString;
    TopMenuItem.OnClick := MenuItemClick;
    MainMenu.Items.Add(TopMenuItem);
     TopMenuItem := MainMenu.Items[i];

    for j := 0 to 10 do
    begin
      MenuItem := TMenuItem.Create(MainMenu);
      MenuItem.Caption := 'Menu item #' + j.ToString;
      MenuItem.OnClick := MenuItemClick;
      TopMenuItem.Add(MenuItem);
      MenuItem := TopMenuItem.Items[j];

      for k := 0 to 10 do
      begin
        SubMenuItem := TMenuItem.Create(MainMenu);
        SubMenuItem.Caption := 'Sub Menu item #' + k.ToString;
        SubMenuItem.OnClick := MenuItemClick;
        MenuItem.Add(SubMenuItem);
        SubMenuItem := MenuItem.Items[k];
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;


procedure TForm17.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CreateMainMenu;
end;

procedure TForm17.MenuItemClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;
```